# Run on EDT after delay

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I want to close a dialog after a specified timeout. So far I have the following method:

```
public static void addTimeout(final Component c, long timeout) {
    Timer t = new Timer(c.getName() + "-TimeoutTimer");
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (c.isVisible()) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        c.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, timeout);
}
```

However, I would like to know if there is a more compact way to write it. For example, avoiding to set a timer and just calling a method to run code on EDT with a specified delay. Is that possible?

Comment: You can declare a static `Timer` and reuse the same `Timer`. Same thing goes for an `Executor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. If you switch to using the (more modern) `java.util.concurrent` way of doing things, you can use two lambdas and do it like this:

```
public static void addTimeout(final Component c, long timeout) {
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> {
        if (c.isVisible()) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                c.setVisible(false);
            });
        }
        return null;
    }, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

...which is more compact. But aside from switching to a scheduled thread executor, it's really just syntactic sugar on what you have above.

(Side note: If actually using the above code, it'd probably be better to store the result of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` for future invocations.)